# How to express a group's ratio using individual's ratio?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Can someone help to take a look? Not sure how to start, all numbers are non-negative

> express $\frac{S_{1} + S_{2}}{N_{1} + N_{2}}$ using $\frac{S_{1}}{N_{1}}$ and  $\frac{S_{2}}{N_{2}}$, would you say $\frac{S_{1} + S_{2}}{N_{1} + N_{2}}$ is in between $\frac{S_{1}}{N_{1}}$ and  $\frac{S_{2}}{N_{2}}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** (I assume all values are non-negative.) The combined expression is a so-called *volume-weighted average* of the individual expressions.

The weight for $S_i/N_i$ is $N_i$.

A (volume-)weighted average always lies between the smallest and the largest of the terms being averaged. If there are only two such terms, one is the smallest and the other is the largest.

The average can be bounded below by replacing all of the $S_i$ with the smallest one, and bounded above by replacing all of them with the largest one. This produces the desired inequalities.

*Note:* Here, the volume-weighted average is 
$[N_1(S_1/N_1) + N_2(S_2/N_2)]/(N_1+N_2)$. In general, a weighted average of terms $t_i$ is $\left(\sum_i w_it_i\right)/\left(\sum_i w_i\right)$. In your case, the terms $t_i = S_i/N_i$ and the weights $w_i=N_i$.

Comment: how to express the volume-weighted average using the individual expression?

Comment: $[N_1(S_1/N_1) + N_2(S_2/N_2)]/(N_1+N_2)$. In general, a weighted average of terms $t_i$ is $\sum_i w_it_i/\sum_i w_i$. In your case, the terms $t_i = S_i/N_i$ and the weights $w_i=N_i$. Will add this to my answer.